# Sending file from Java server to Javascript client - problem processing file client-side

Tags: javascript, java

I have a java server running jetty that is to send a base64 encoded excel file as a response to a client request.
Upon receiving the response on the client, I am able to access/decode the response, however, the download results in a file that cannot be opened by excel.

opening the resulting client file in a text editor looks just like a valid excel file would (bunch of hex). What else am I leaving out?

Java Code (using [spark](http://sparkjava.com/)):

```java
get("/file", (request, response) -> {
   File file = new File(".\\file.xlsx");
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
   byte[] buff = new byte[(int)file.length()];
   int bytesRead = 0;
   ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   while((bytesRead = is.read(buff)) != -1){
    bao.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
   }
   is.close();
   byte[data] = bao.toByteArray();

   response.header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
   //creates an encoded string as intended   
   response.body(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(data)));
   return response.body();

});
```

Javascript code (vanilla):

```
function download(window) {
    let text;
    let blob;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        //decodes base64 encoded response (file) from server
        text = window.atob(e.srcElement.result);
        blob = new Blob([text], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"})

        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = url;
        downloadLink.download = "excelFile.xlsx";
        downloadLink.click();
        downloadLink.remove();
    }

    fetch("http://javaServer.com/file")
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        this.blob = blob;
        //triggers 'onloadend' event handler
        reader.readAsText(blob);
    });
}
download(window);
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to send it base64 encoded? Or you're forgetting to unencode it

Comment: @Mark I was under the impression that I had to send it encoded as a string after parsing the file with the inputStream? But I did unencode on line 6 (`text = window.atob(e.srcElement.result);`) of the the javascript code block.

Edit: I should mention that the `response.body(data)` (java - sets the body of the response) only takes a string

Comment: I did also try sending the response unencoded by using `bao.toString()` to send the ByteArrayOutputStream directly. Same result though :/